# SQL Not in subquery

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently using this query:

```
select *
from [dbo].[tf_invoices_sales] v 
inner join dbo.vw_Kalender k on v.[fin.trs.line.matchdate] = k.datum 
where  v.[fin.trs.head.code] = 'VRK' 
and [fin.trs.line.invnumber] not in 
    (select invoicenumber from [dbo].[tf_partial_payments])
```

The output for **invoicenumber 20026** will be blank. That invoicenumber belongs to 2 offices. Office 100 with this invoicenumber is in *[dbo].[tf_partial_payments]*. Office 200 with this invoicenumber is not in *[dbo].[tf_partial_payments]*. So the desired output has to be **invoicenumber 20026 with office 200**

I've already tried this: `concat([fin.trs.line.invnumber], [fin.trs.head.office])  not in (select concat(invoicenumber, office) from [dbo].[tf_partial_payments])`

This query is way to slow.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you *need* `SELECT *`? I would firstly reduce the columns you return to those you actually need. As for the performance, can you [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) please? Adding the definition of your tables *and* their indexes will greatly help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery instead of `not in`

```
select
  *
from
  [dbo].[tf_invoices_sales] v 
  inner join dbo.vw_Kalender k on v.[fin.trs.line.matchdate] = k.datum 
where 
  v.[fin.trs.head.code] = 'VRK'
  and not exists (
    select 1 from [dbo].[tf_partial_payments]
    where invoicenumber = v.[fin.trs.line.invnumber] and office = v.office
  )
```

Make sure that `tf_partial_payments` has an index over `([fin.trs.line.invnumber], office)`, i.e. both fields in the same index, not two separate indexes with one field each.

Answer (score 0):

Try left joining on it and adding a discriminator to ensure matching results are excluded.

```
select 
    v.*,
    k.*
from 
   [dbo].[tf_invoices_sales] v 
inner join 
    dbo.vw_Kalender k on v.[fin.trs.line.matchdate] = k.datum
left join
    [dbo].[tf_partial_payments] pp
ON pp.invoicenumber = [fin.trs.line.invnumber]
where  
    v.[fin.trs.head.code] = 'VRK' 
and pp.invoicenumber IS NULL
```